# Como obter o nome de uma variável?

Tags: ruby, variáveis, reflexão, metaprogramação

Existe alguma forma de obter o nome de uma variável utilizando metaprogramação (ou reflexão, acredito que seja um sinônimo) em Ruby? Quero algo parecido com o [`nameof`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/nameof) do C#.

Estava procurando algo como:

```
minha_variavel = "valor"
minha_variavel.name
=> "minha_variavel"
```

Tentei utilizar vários métodos, mas sem sucesso. Cheguei até utilizar o `Object#object_id` para trabalhar com o objeto, mas não obtive o resultado que eu esperava:

```
ObjectSpace._id2ref(minha_variavel.object_id)
=> "valor"
```

O `ObjectSpace#_id2ref` obtém a instância em si, que é evaluada pelo seu valor. O que quero é o nome atribuído ao objeto.

É possível? Se não, o que impossibilita, [se em outras linguagens esse tipo de situação pode ser resolvido](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/nameof)?

Comment: Por curiosidade, há alguma aplicação prática em obter o nome de uma variável? Algo que motive fazer `nameof(var)` ao invés de apenas `"var"`?

Comment: Uma aplicação seria _logging_. Talvez poupar retrabalho. E variáveis, classes ou afins podem ser criados de forma dinâmica em alguns contextos @AndersonCarlosWoss

Comment: Creio que Ruby não tenha essa feature pois ela parece ser desnecessária em linguagens de script (script languages), o que não é o caso de C# que é compilada e a referência para o nome das variáveis muda no binário. Veja essa resposta sobre o [nameof](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31695982/1042324). E para _logging_ eu acredito que o [Kernel#set_trac_func](http://devdocs.io/ruby~2.5/kernel#method-i-set_trace_func) seja suficiente. (E claro que se você tiver um exemplo real do nameof aplicado a _logging_ com Ruby seria muito útil)